# Python Click Option Backspace

Tags: python, python-click

I'm using a few `@click.option()` statements in my `CLI program`.

When the program runs and the user enters in a value, and the backspace key is pressed, it does not process the backspace input as a backspace and outputs raw characters in the input field instead.

I've gone through the Click package `documentation` and searched online, but I've not come across anything useful.

Is anyone aware of a way to get the backspace to work as expected in the event that the user needs to correct their input before hitting Enter?

Thanks.

Comment: Please consider reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for a higher chance to get a good answer.

Comment: Please include your code in your question.

Comment: I've fixed the issue. It had nothing to do with the Click package and was actually related to how the terminal emulator I'm using, SecureCRT (VT100) represents the BackSpace <--- key.

Comment: Even if you have fixed your problem, please edit your answer to include the code you were using before and perhaps also add an edit section where you point out how you fixed it, this way any future viewers who view the post will be helped by it too. And as pointed out by @SergiyKolesnikov you should read the help section once it helps improve the questions asked.